# Python connector error - no result set. Previous query contains truncated results

Tags: python, mysql, exception, mysql-connector

I'm hoping someone might have seen something similar to this before, I have no idea what to do next to debug it.

If I run a mysql query of the below form on a particular table, I get a result set returned successfully, but it will only contain up to 165 rows - ie if I add 'limit 200', I still get a result set, but only containing 165 rows. If I print the query that is being run and paste it into a mysql console I can get more than 100,000 results returned.

select  table1.field1,table2.field2, from table1 left join table2 on table2.keyfield = table1.keyfield;

If I impose a limit of 165 rows on the query, I can then run another query. If I don't impose a limit of 165 or less, when I try to execute the next query I get an exception 'mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from'

I get the same results running the Python script in Windows and Linux. The destination MySQL server is V8.0.32, running on a Linux box.

Pseudocode below, I've only removed the mysql credentials and the actual query (I can include the actual query if that helps, but have verified that it runs as described in the mysql console, returning >100,000 results). Can anyone offer any suggestions?

````
    
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    ....credentials...
)

cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
query = "select  table1.field1,table1.field2,table1.field3,table2.field4, table2.field5  from table1 left join table2 on table2.keyfield = table1.keyfield;"    
cursor.execute(query,[])
rows = cursor.fetchall()
# if I print len(rows), there will only be 165 items despite there being > 100,000 results

# If I now run the below, I'll get 'mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from'
query = "select * from table1;"
cursor.execute(query,[])
rows = cursor.fetchall()```
````

Answer (score 0):

After debugging some other weird behaviour - where selects return fewer results through python than through a mysql client - I've found that changing my cursor request to:
`cursor = db.cursor(prepared=True)`

...And then converting each string result from a byte array using .decode() seems to fix the problem, but I have no idea why! Just offering this as a workaround in case someone else has a similar problem